# How can I create dynamic INT variables for daily datasize variations

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Each day I receive many different files from different vendors, and the sizes are vastly different. I am looking for some dynamic code that will decide what is relevant across all files. I would like to think thru how to break this file into components (`df1, df2, df3` for example) which will make it easier for analysis.

Basically the first 6 lines are for overall information about the store (`df1`).

The 2nd component is reserved for specific item sales (starting on row 9, ending in a DIFFERENT row in every file), and I'm not sure how to capture that. I have tried something along the lines of

```
numb = df.loc['Type of payment'].index[0] - 2
```

but it is bringing in the tuple instead of the row location (int). How can i save `upperrange` and `lowerrange` to be a dynamic (int) so that each day it will bring in the correct df2 data I am looking for?

The same problem exists at the bottom under "Type of payment" - you will notice that crypto is included for the 1st day but not the 2nd. I need to find a way to get a dynamic range to remove erroneous info and keep the integrity of the rest. I think finding the `lowerrange` will allow me to capture from that point to the end of the sheet, but I'm open to suggestions.

```
df = pd.read_csv('GMSALES.csv', skipfooter=2)
upperrange = df.loc['Item Number']  #brings in tuple
lowerrange = df.loc['Type of payment'] #brings in tuple

df1 = df.iloc[:,7] #this works
df2 = df.iloc[:('upperrange':'lowerrange')] # this is what I would like to get to
df3 = df.iloc[:(lowerrange:)]               # this is what I would like to get to
```

[image: GMSALES]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your organizational problem is that your data comes in as a spreadsheet that is used for *physical* organization more than *functional* organization.  The "columns" are merely typographical tabs.  The file contains several types of heterogeneous data; you are right in wanting to reorganize this into individual data frames.

Very simply, you need to parse the file, customer by customer -- either before or after reading it into RAM.

From your current organization, this involves simply scanning the "df2" range of your heterogeneous data frame.  I think that the simplest way is to start from row 7 and look for "Item Number" in column `A`; that is your row of column names.  Then scan until you find a row with nothing in column `A`; back up one row, and that gives you `lowerrange`.

Repeat with the payments: find the next row with "Type of payment".  I will assume that you have some way to discriminate payment types from fake data, such as a list of legal payment types (strings). Scan from "Type of Payment" until you find a row with something other than a legal payment type; the previous row is your `lowerrange` for `df3`.

Can you take it form there?